# Problem with Twitter search api

Tags: ruby-on-rails

working when using this in rails c

```
client = TwitterSearch::Client.new('campvote')

tweets = client.query('#barcampmlk2 #railsforzombies +1')
```

but not when `BarcampSession.update_twitter!` it retune empty hash

```
require 'twitter_search'
class BarcampSession < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :hash_tag , :format => {:with => /^#\w+/ } , :presence => true ,:uniqueness => true
    validates :name , :presence => true 
    validates :email , :presence => true , :format => {:with => /((\S+)@(\S{3}[a-zA-z0-9)]\S*))/ }
    validates :handphone, :presence => true 

    def self.update_twitter!
        client = TwitterSearch::Client.new('campvote')
        BarcampSession.all.each do |sess|
            tweets = client.query('#barcampmlk2 #{sess.hash_tag} +1')
            puts tweets.to_yaml
        end

    end
end
```

it return

```
rb(main):014:0> BarcampSession.update_twitter!
--- !seq:TwitterSearch::Tweets []

=> [#<BarcampSession id: 1, hash_tag: "#railsforzombies", name: "wizztjh", email: "wiz123tjh@gmail.com", handphone: "1234006", since: nil, created_at: "2010-12-14 18:28:01", updated_at: "2010-12-14 18:28:01">]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String interpolation works only with double quotes, not single quotes. Change the line

```
tweets = client.query('#barcampmlk2 #{sess.hash_tag} +1')
```

to

```
tweets = client.query("#barcampmlk2 #{sess.hash_tag} +1")
```